# Получение обновлений от Telegram Bot API в Android

Tags: android, android-sdk, telegram

Мне в программе нужно получать сообщения от Telegram бота. 
Грубо-говоря, удаленное управление некоторыми функциями.

Программа знает только токен бота и его методы, получается, что сейчас мне нужно просто слать http-запрос и получать ответ с некоторой периодичностью.

Вариант решения : вынести логику в сервис и тупо стучаться каждые 2 минуты.

Проблема: зря трачу ресурсы, так как может прийти одно сообщения в час, или 30 за 5 минут.

Есть ли более подходящее решение?

Comment: Только если бот может уведомить вас об обновлениях ,можете попробовать заставить его отправлять вам `PUSH`- уведомление

Comment: @metalurgus Бот может послать пуш только пользователю Телеграмма?

Ведь у меня программа только использует апи и аутентификация проходит по токену бота.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вот это:
https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#setwebhook

Веб-хуки очень экономны. Есть и прекрасная их реализация на Java:
https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots